# Request.post on already uploaded image file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am using Angularjs and nodejs in the project and working on file uploads. I want to send the post request to the url endpoint in a secure way as I need to attach accesstoken with the request. So the way I did this was, I added the directive to choose the file from UI and once it gets the file, I append it using FormData() like this in the controller

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file',myFile);
```

and sending this formdata object to the nodejs server like mentioned here http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

expect this request will be going to my nodejs server url from there I will be making another post request to external web service

```
$http.post('api/collections/upload',fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {
        'Content-type': undefined
     }
});
```

So it will attach the right content-type and boundaries in the request. I am getting the file on server side nodejs when I do

```
function(req,res){
  console.log(req.files); //I am able to see the file content
}
```

It is uploaded on the nodejs server side. 
Now I want to make a post request using the req.files to a different endpoint along with proper accessToken and headers. Tried many things but not able to make the request go thru. Not sure how can I attach the imagedata/ req.files along with the request. I tried these two things mentioned in request npm module https://www.npmjs.org/package/request

1)

```
request.post({
    url: 'https://www.example.com/uploadImage',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': <accessToken>,
      'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: req.files
 });
```

Don't know how can I attach and binary data with this request and how can I put boundary. Is boundary needed when you want to send the uploaded image with this request?

2)

```
fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path, {encoding: base64}).pipe(request.post({
    url: 'https://www.example.com/uploadImage',
    headers: {
     'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }));
```

Can someone please suggest some ideas on how can I send this post request using request npm module? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your suggestion helped me to atleast know what I was trying was right. Another article that solved my problem was this http://aguacatelang.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/post-photo-from-node-js-to-facebook/ .Basically, here is what I did and it worked. Thanks for your suggestion.

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/image.jpg'));

var options = {
    url: 'https://www.example.com/uploadImage?access_token='+ <accesstoken>,
    headers: form.getHeaders()
};

form.pipe(request.post(options,function(err,res){
    if(err){
      log.debug(err);
    }
    else {
      log.debug(res);
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation here has lots of examples of doing exactly what you describe:

https://github.com/mikeal/request#streaming

As can be seen in that link, the *request* library adds a `.pipe()` method to your http's `req` object, which you should be able to use like the examples in the link:

```
function(req, res) {
  req.pipe(request.post('https://www.example.com/uploadImage');
}
```

Or something similar.

You were nearly there with your #2 try, but that would only work if you have previously written the file out to disk and were reading it in with `fs.createReadStream()`